# A middle length riddle

Tags: riddle, word, english

> You wouldn't be here without me
>   I am feared by many
>   and obsessed over by some
>   I can purify you by shocking you with an ordeal
>   People might call me amicable but you should stay away from me
>   I end your friendships
>   I can be your end
>   and your eternity
>   If your roots run deep you may be born of me

Who or what am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filling out lines 5, 6, 7 & 9 (Raul Torry has been confirmed correct for all others):
`People might call me amicable but you should stay away from me`

> Friendly Fire - a nice-sounding name for something you absolutely do not want to experience. (hagfy was first with this after translating their comment)

`I end your friendships` (I don't believe I've got this one right)

> A 'Flame War', as in an internet discussion gone off the rails ...not really an example of a friendship, I know.

`I can be your end`

> You can be 'Fired' from a job.

`If your roots run deep you may be born of me`

> Forest fires pave the way for new growth, with deep roots being safe from the blaze on the surface. (following Rubio's link, I see they were first)

Answer (score 9):

I think you are:

> The fire

You wouldn't be here without me

> Human beings depend on fire to live.

I am feared by many

> Many people are afraid of fire

and obsessed over by some

> And others love it. (Pyromania)

I can purify you by shocking you with an ordeal

> Fire is used in rituals to purify

People might call me amicable but you should stay away from me

> Most people know how to handle it, but sometimes it can get out of control

I end your friendships

> Fire can kill your friends in a fire

I can be your end

> Or even you

and your eternity

> Well, If you've been bad in life, you can go to hell (haha)

If your roots run deep you may be born of me

> There is a technique of cultivation based on burning areas (mostly Tropical areas) See [Shifting Cultivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_cultivation)

Comment: Upvoting as you have got the right answer but haven't got all of the hints correct yet. re-try lines 5,6,7 and 9 =)

Comment: [This may help (ROT13)](http://www.webutils.pl/index.php?idx=rot&mode=rot13&dec=DECODE&data=Chevsl%3A+%22gevny+ol+sver%22.+Ebbgf%3A+fbzr+gerrf+unir+frrq+pbarf+gung+bayl+bcra+jura+ohearq+%28frr+uggcf%3A%2F%2Fjjj.oevgnaavpn.pbz%2Fyvfg%2F5-nznmvat-nqncgngvbaf-bs-clebculgvp-cynagf+%235%29.+Nyfb+va+fbzr+qrafr+sberfgf+bayl+n+sver+pyrnef+gur+jnl+sbe+arj+gerrf+gb+tebj.)

Comment: I feel like rot13(sevraqyl sver) is part of 5 or 6?

Comment: @Rubio, how do you add a description to the link you linked too? :)